# Ubuntu 13.04 pulseaudio doesn't load

Tags: pulseaudio

I have just installed pulseaudio to my new, fresh ubuntu 13.04, but it doesn't start. When I press on PulseAudio Equalizer icon, nothing happens. Any ideas, what could be wrong?

Comment: try creating a `.pulse` folder in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with my PulseAudio Equalizer on 13.04. I purged it and reinstalled. Seems better. Update for good measuer too. I'm using the ppa as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio-equalizer
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudu apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```